# Derive polar coordinate version of Laplacian from spherical one?

Tags: polar-coordinates, spherical-coordinates, laplacian

Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^3\to\mathbb{R}$. The Laplacian of $f$ in spherical coordinates is
$\nabla^2 f(r, \phi, \theta) = \frac 1 {r^2} \frac {\partial} {\partial r} \left ( r^2 \frac {\partial f} {\partial r} \right ) 
+ \frac 1 {r^2 \sin \phi} \frac {\partial} {\partial \phi} \left ( \sin \phi \frac {\partial f} {\partial \phi} \right )
+ \frac 1 {r^2 \sin^2 \phi} \frac {\partial^2 f} {\partial \theta^2}$.

Suppose $g:\mathbb{R}^2\to\mathbb{R}$. The Laplacian of $g$ in polar coordinates is
$\nabla^2 g(r, \theta) = \frac 1 r \frac {\partial} {\partial r} \left ( r \frac {\partial g} {\partial r} \right ) 
+ \frac 1 {r^2} \frac {\partial^2 g} {\partial \theta^2}$.

Is there a way to derive the polar version from the spherical one?

Comment: Set $\phi = \pi/2$.

Comment: That was my first idea too, but it doesn't seem to work.  It's off by $\frac 1 r \frac {\partial g} {\partial r}$.